# Change Swift Custom Class Programmatically

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to change the custom class of storyboard elements programatically. I have an Objective C library that defines the colors of this audio meter element. I want to change the color of each element depending on some variables. To do this, I need to change the custom class of the element to a separate class of the same library that I duplicated but changed the colors.

How do I change the custom class programmatically.

My initializer array of meters is

```
    @IBOutlet var ChannelMeter: [F3BarGauge]!
```

And the class is F3BarGauge.

I need to be able to change any of those meters programmatically to F3BarGaugeBlue. Is this possible?

Here is the library I am using.

https://github.com/ChiefPilot/F3BarGauge

Comment: You can modify the properties of an object, but you can’t change an object’s class. You might need to subclass the class in the library to make your own implementation that provides the ability to change colour. You could replace a given meter with your new class type but you cannot mix different types in an array.

Comment: How would that subclass work? I'm more novice when it comes to coding so I haven't implemented subclasses before. If you look at the library in the link, you will easily see where color is defined. I need to be able to change the color of each meter.

Comment: It all seems to be in Objective-C rather than Swift. I’m not so familiar with Obj-C.

Comment: Unless I am missing something I can't see the class F3BarGaugeBlue in that library.  I can just see the F3BarGauge class which then has properties to change the colours as required.

Comment: Correct, I was going to duplicate the library, change the colors and rename it so I could point the meters to a different library to change the color. That was the hope at least. I'm not sure if that's how you would do it though?